# VLC Live Video Streaming on Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, video-streaming, vlc, windows-phone, live-video

I'm using [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) to stream video live from my webcam 
i do as follows:
File > Stream > Capture Device > Display locally > http > Activate Transcoding > WMV+WMA(ASF) > Add HTTP, Port 8080, Destination /go.wmv

So the link to my streaming is like this: `http://localhost:8080/go.wmv`
I tested it and it works in another instance of VLC.

Now in Windows Phone 7, I simply drag and drop media element, create 3 buttons
first button:
`mediaElement1.Source=new URI(http://localhost:8080/go.wmv);`
second button:
`mediaElement1.Play();`
third button:
`mediaElement1.Stop();`

`mediaElement` is supposed to support this.
Why is it not working?

Comment: Please clarify - you mention a webcam, and also a phone.  Are you streaming from the camera on the phone? You have a filename (go.wmv) in your link - are you streaming to a file?

Answer (score 0):

`localhost` from your phone is, well, your phone. You'd need to specify the name of the PC hosting the webcam to connect. If they are not on the same network, you would need to specify the fully qualified domain name of the host.

Comment: i did specified it like this, http:192.168.0.2:8080 , and also doesn't work

Comment: 192.168.x.x is a non-routable address, useful only WITHIN a local network (ie. a house, business). Therefore, it cannot get to your phone unless the phone is also on that same network. Check the IP address of your phone, but I doubt it is. (I realize I am writing for posterity).