# Live Video Streaming on Windows Phone 7 using VLC?

Tags: windows-phone-7, video-streaming, vlc

I want to receive and play live video streaming on Windows Phone 7

I'm using VLC Player to Achieve that.

(HTTP, destination with .wmv extension ,  transcoding into wmv )

on the Windows Phone 7
I drag and drop  media element the code like that
mediaElement1.Source=new URI(http://localhost:8080/go.wmv

but nothing is played
plz help

Comment: As weird as it may seem, I dont think wmv is supported on windows phone 7 - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff462087(v=vs.92).aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [VLC Live Video Streaming on Windows Phone 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10441071/vlc-live-video-streaming-on-windows-phone-7)

Answer (score 0):

Convert the stream in H264 instead of wmv. This should work.